# Dax First time pass rate

Tags: dax

I'm trying to create a measure to calculate first time past rate for a location.

So if I have a day where there are ten failures and one pass on an item, it would be a first time pass rate of zero%.

[image]

So the First time pass rate should be 60%:

[image]

[image]

```
FirsTimePassed = CALCULATE(MIN(ATP[Result Date]), ALLEXCEPT(ATP,ATP[Location Name]),FILTER(ATP,ATP[Pass/Fail]="Pass"))
firstime = CALCULATE(MIN(ATP[Result Date]), ALLEXCEPT(ATP,ATP[Location Name]))

FirstTimePassedCount = 
VAR SerailCount = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(ATP[Location Name]),ALL(ATP))
VAR PassedCount = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(ATP[Location Name]),FILTER(ATP,ATP[firstime]=ATP[FirsTimePassed]))
Return PassedCount/SerailCount
```

Comment: can you provide a small data set to example your starting point followed by the expected results?  What have you tried so far and what issue did you face?

Comment: Ok sure  @DarylWenman-Bateson

Fail ,07/05/2020 05:17:41 AM, Tooth 1
Fail, 07/05/2020 05:43:31 AM , Tooth 1
Fail, 07/05/2020 05:54:43 AM, Tooth 1
Pass 07/09/2020 05:38:10 AM Tooth 1
Fail 07/10/2020 05:31:55 AM Tooth 1
Fail 07/10/2020 05:43:39 AM Tooth 1
Pass 07/10/2020 05:46:07 AM Tooth 1
Fail 07/24/2020 05:16:59 AM Tooth 1
Pass 07/24/2020 05:22:50 AM Tooth 1
Pass 08/12/2020 04:45:49 AM Tooth 1
Pass 08/14/2020 04:48:16 AM Tooth 1
Fail 12/16/2020 05:35:47 AM Tooth 1
Pass 12/16/2020 05:39:13 AM Tooth 1

First time pass rate would be 2/13=0.15. I've tired the following

Comment: @DarylWenman-Bateson. I've updated my initial post with more data and what I have done. Thanks a lot. !